# How should I set these associations up properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to build a blog-style app.  I have 3 models - Users, Projects and Posts.
Users have_many projects, users have_many posts.
Projects belong_to users, projects have_many posts
Posts belong_to Users, posts belong_to projects

I have tried setting up the project a number of different ways, following a range of published solutions and I keep hitting many errors. The latest and greatest error

At the moment I am hitting a ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey in PostsController#create
SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed error.

Answer (score 0):

`rails generate model Project title:string user:references` this command will make the project belong to a user and the user model add has_many projects
the same thing applies for posts

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the User model and table already generated
then generate scaffold

`rails g scaffold Post user:references`

rails will create a migration that adds a column named user_id to the Post table and creates an index on it.
For both tables.
Rails will also add belongs_to :user in the Post model.

You can add a has_many to a model as long as another model belongs_to the first model and has a migration with the foreign key column.
The same should be done to the Project Model
as the association between projects and posts use the same concept of users and posts